# How i can know, how chaging value on EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-seekbar

I have an EditText which accepts changes from keyboard or seekBar. I want know,  changing makes input from keyboard or changing from seekBar. How i can make this?

"How you changed the value of the edit text based on seekbar?" Answer:

```
  SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener seekBarListener = new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

    ...

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
            boolean fromUser) {
        float degree = (float)progress/10;
        int value = (int) Math.pow(10, degree);
        editTextCoins.setText(String.valueOf(value));

    }

};
```

Comment: How you changed the value of the edit text based on seekbar? Can you post your code

Comment: @Sripathi i answerув youк question

Comment: Store value in two variable one for seekBar and one for Keyboard if change occur then replace variable value and match them. if value match from seekBar then value have change through seekBar else KeyBoard.

Comment: Set a boolean in the onProgressChanged() and check the boolean. That will show you that which one cause change in the edittext.

Answer (score 0):

```
String seekBarText;
@Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
            boolean fromUser) {
        float degree = (float)progress/10;
        int value = (int) Math.pow(10, degree);
        editTextCoins.setText(String.valueOf(value));
seekBarText=(String.valueOf(value));

    }

};
if(seekBarText.equals(editTextCoins.getText().toString()){
//value change from seekBar
}
else{
//value change from Keyboard
}
```